# Prove that the sequence {$n^{\frac{1}{2}}$} diverges where $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

My attempt :

I have tried to show by contradiction: let $L$ be the limit of the sequence. Then
 $-e<n^{\frac{1}{2}}- L <e$  for all  $n>N$ and $e> 0$ which implies that
 $ (L-e)^2< n<(L+e)^2$ . However since $(L+e)^2 $ is a real number we can always choose infinitely many natural numbers which are greater than it and for which the equation doesn't hold. Am I correct?

Comment: The OP's attempt shows that the outer brackets have no meaning.

Comment: I just wanted to show that it is a sequence , the outer brackets dont have a meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm sad to say that made the question less interesting for me. No matter. The answerers have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost right but you cannot square an inequality involving negative numbers. So forget about the left hand in equality and look at $n^{1/2} <L+\epsilon$. You have to first prove that $L \geq 0$ so that you can square this in equality and get a contradiction as you have done.

Comment: How do I show that $L>=0$ . Since It is a sequence of natural numbers then it cannot converge to a negative number . This is what I can think of ..

Comment: @smita If $L <0$ choose $\epsilon \in (0, -L)$. Then the in equality $n^{12/} <L+\epsilon$ leads to a contradiction. Hence we must have $L \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, but it is more natural to note that $\left(\sqrt n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is unbounded, whereas every convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. Let us see if the OP has something to say about it.